# Why is my MySql query not returning the returning rows I want?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a hotel rate system and am in a situation where some of the records which I don't want is displaying. Here's my table

```
room id    room_name    rate_starts   rate_ends    single_room   double_room
1          standard     2014-01-01    2014-02-28   150           200
1          standard     2014-03-01    2014-03-05   200           250
1          standard     2014-03-06    2014-03-31   300           350
2          Garden Villa 2014-01-01    2014-02-28   300           400
```

Here is my MySQL query

```
    SELECT room_id, room_name, 
      SUM(`single_room` * DateDiff(
          Least(rate_ends + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '$ends'),
          Greatest(rate_starts, '$starts')
        )) AS Total
    FROM
        room_rate
    WHERE
          hotel_id   = '$hotel_id' AND
          rate_ends >= '$starts' AND
          rate_starts <= '$ends'              
          GROUP BY room_id
```

here is my search parameter `($starts)'2014-02-27'` to `($ends)'2014-03-02'`

here is my result

```
Standard room 500
Garden Villa 600
```

for the time am searching only for single_room rates.

Actually i don't want to display Garden villa because that room rate is not complete. That room does not have the date range between 2014-03-01  to  2014-03-05. However it is still displaying the first date range results.

I hope you understood my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have $starts and $ends mixed, is that on purpose?

Comment: I think you have your WHERE clause wrong should it not be rate_ends <= '$ends' and rate_starts >= '$starts' ?

Comment: the above code is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the room rate to be in your start-end search interval, use

```
  WHERE
          hotel_id   = '$hotel_id' AND
          rate_starts>= '$starts' AND -- room rate starts in the search interval
          rate_ends<= '$ends'     --room rate ends in the search interval
```

we need another way to check availability 
table:

```
room_id, date, running_availability:



select room_id, date,  
  (select sum(availability from (select room_id, rate_starts as date, 1 as availability from     table
  union all
  select room_id, rate_ends, -1 as availability from table) as av2 where av1.date <= av2.date) as running_availability
from
(select room_id, rate_starts as date, 1 as availability from table
union all
select room_id, rate_ends, -1 as availability from table) as av2
```

Now you can check if the room is ever unavailable in your time interval (running_avaliability!=0 and date between start and end)

If you want to check price and availability in one go, you need to join the two. For the sake of readability, let's jsut call this table 'available'

```
SELECT room_id, room_name, 
  SUM(`single_room` * DateDiff(
      Least(rate_ends + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '$ends'),
      Greatest(rate_starts, '$starts')
    )) AS Total
FROM
    room_rate
    left join 
    (select * from available where running_availability!=1) av 
    on av.date between '$starts' and '$ends'   
WHERE
      hotel_id   = '$hotel_id' AND
      rate_ends >= '$starts' AND
      rate_starts <= '$ends'    
      and av.date is null          
      GROUP BY room_id
```

Comment: @user2981233 what result do you expect exactly?

Comment: i want only standard room 500. Because garden villa rate is not complete. For garden villa second date range is not there so only first date range total is querying.

Comment: you need a proper time interval comparison query; basically you want to be sure there's no interruptions in room availability

Comment: could you please provide me with a solution. Am totally out of mind.

Comment: added solution with join, just rename the table name

Comment: i did not test your availability query. However could you please provide me a simple way to do this with rates and availability.

Comment: to make most out of your code please give me the availability table structure

Comment: it's your table structure, just replace the word 'table' with your table name. Test the availability. There is no simpler, correct way. It's one query for both availability and sum. Please take one single minute and try it, I took 20 minutes to write this for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I created my 'available' table. Columns are available_id, date, running_availability. However still the same problem occurs. Am searching $hotel_id= 1, $starts= 2014-02-27, $ends= 2014-03-02. And the result is still coming with Garden villa. As i mentioned the $starts falls in first date range. And $ends falls in second date range. So in Garden villa the second date range is not provided in database. So Garden villa rate is not complete. it means i should not display Garden villa.

Comment: try changing the where clause, where running_availability!=1

Comment: actually at first i do not want to go along with availability. I only want to show the rates. am searching for a solution with rates only. I guess you still did not understand my problem.

Comment: you want the rates only if the room is available. ' Because garden villa rate is not complete'=not available for the whole period. So you need to check if the room is 'complete' or available for that period

Comment: lets not talk about any availability. I want to show the rates only. for example if a i search from 2014-02-27 to 2014-03-03. The total rate i should get.

Comment: in that case, you don't have an issue at all, garden villa qualifies and your initial query returns the desired result.

Comment: am sorry my result is not correct. if i search from 2014-02-27 to 2014-03-03 i i get the two room with its rate. However Garden villa rate is from 2014-02-27 to 2014-02-28. Its because in the database garden villa does not have the date range between 2014-03-01 onwards.

Comment: i got the right answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201877/room-rates-returning-with-correct-results-and-wrong-results/21202009?noredirect=1#comment31927783_21202009