# Room rates returning with correct results and wrong results

Tags: mysql

Hi all the experts out there. Am having a big issue here and am still working to find a solution.
I have a reservation system in which it shows the hotel rates only. once a customer request a room we check availability manually by contacting the hotel. So the availability part we do not want to implement no the website. However the rate system is having a little problem. For example if i search for room rates from 2014-02-27 to 2014-03-02 which falls in to two date ranges i get two results in which one result is not fully completed. 
Here is my database

```
    room id    room_name    rate_starts   rate_ends    single_room   double_room
    1          standard     2014-01-01    2014-02-28   150           200
    1          standard     2014-03-01    2014-03-05   200           250
    1          standard     2014-03-06    2014-03-31   300           350
    2          Garden Villa 2014-01-01    2014-02-28   300           400
```

Here is my query

```
     SELECT room_id, room_name, 
     SUM(`single_room` * DateDiff(
      Least(rate_ends + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '$ends'),
      Greatest(rate_starts, '$starts')
     )) AS Total
     FROM
     room_rate
     WHERE
      hotel_id   = '$hotel_id' AND
      rate_ends >= '$starts' AND
      rate_starts <= '$ends'              
      GROUP BY room_id
```

here is my result

```
    Standard room 500
    Garden Villa 600
```

Am expecting this answer
        Standard room 500

Here is a little explanation on what am really in to. My search is from 2014-02-27 to 2014-03-02 which is falling in to two date ranges in the database. 
        Standard room (150 X 02 = 300 + 200 X 01 = 200) = 500
        Garden villa (300 X 02 = 600 + this date range is not provided in DB) = 600

this means that the Garden villa rate is not fully completed as per my search request. So i should not display the garden villa rates. I hope all the genius people out there would consider finding me a solution to this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing date ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/comparing-date-ranges)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT room_id, room_name, 
    SUM(single_room * DateDiff(
    Least(rate_ends + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '$ends'),
    Greatest(rate_starts, '$starts')
    )) AS Total, 
    sum(DateDiff(
    Least(rate_ends + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '$ends'),
    Greatest(rate_starts, '$starts')
    )) as num_days
    FROM
   room_rate 
   WHERE
   rate_ends >= '$starts' AND
   rate_starts <= '$ends' 
   GROUP BY 
   room_id
   having 
   sum(DateDiff(
   Least(rate_ends + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '$ends'),
   Greatest(rate_starts, '$starts')
   )) = datediff('$ends', '$starts')
```

This answer is working fine and all thanks goes to @user1455836
three weeks of mind work finally solved

Answer (score 0):

use having clause in your sql query to filter out results with wrong number of days

something like

```
having sum(DateDiff(
     Least(rate_ends + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '$ends'),
      Greatest(rate_starts, '$starts')
     )) = datediff('$ends', '$starts')
```

Comment: this is giving me an empty result

Comment: @user2981233 please take a look at this SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffbed/6

Comment: you answer is working really fine. Now am checking with some other filters. Thanks a lot for your help. I will get back to you shortly

Comment: @ user1455836 you are great. i appreciate for your time

Comment: @user2981233 please post your changes to the code as an answer not an edit to this answer.